# Count distinct count over a large SAS dataset

Tags: count, sas, distinct, proc

I have a SAS dataset for 200million records with Date, Id and amount for year 2022

```
  Have:
      ID       Date         Amount
     101      1/31/2022      50
     102      1/31/2022      100
     101      2/28/2022      25
     .....................
```

I am trying to get the unique # of accounts for each month but the it is taking more than an hour to give me the results

```
    proc sql;
      create table unique as select distinct 
      date,
      count(distinct id) as uniqid
      from Have
      group by date
    quit;
```

Is there an alternate method to have the results quickly?

Comment: Why do you think 1 hour is poor performance?    How long does it just to read all the obs?  Are all the dates the last day of the month?

Comment: Yes. They are last day of the month

Comment: Is the dataset sorted by DATE?  Can an ID appear more than once for the same DATE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One alternate available method is to use `proc freq` with the `nlevels` option and access its ods output. The one catch is that your data must be sorted by `date`. If it is not, you'll need to sort your 200M row table by `date` which could take much longer than a SQL statement alone. If you have to do this, try keeping only the two variables of interest in a temporary table.

```
proc sort data = have(keep=date id)
          out  = have_sorted;
    by date;
run;

ods select none;

proc freq data=have_sorted nlevels;
   by date;
   tables id;
   ods output nlevels=unique_count(keep   = date nlevels 
                                   rename = (nlevels = uniqid)
                                  );
run;
```

Other options include trying to tune your `bufno` and `bufsize` system options. [Check out this case study from SANrd on how this affects I/O](https://sasnrd.com/sas-bufsize-bufno-options-case-study-example/).

Also consider looking into the `%freqyeah` macro which parallelizes `proc freq`: [From FREQing Slow to FREQing Fast: Facilitating a Four-Times-Faster FREQ with Divide-and-Conquer Parallel Processing](https://www.lexjansen.com/pharmasug/2018/AA/PharmaSUG-2018-AA07.pdf)

Comment: How about using `tables id*date` to instead the sort procedure and by statement in freq procedure?

Comment: I gave that a try as well, but it returns a table of unique IDs individually for ID and Date rather than unique IDs for each date.

Answer (score 0):

This probably won't be faster by may help you judge SQL performance.

```
data amount;
   input ID :$3. Date :mmddyy. Amount;
   format date mmddyy10.;
   cards;
101      1/31/2022      50
102      1/31/2022      100
101      2/28/2022      25
101      3/31/2022      50
102      3/31/2022      100
103      4/30/2022      25
103      5/31/2022      50
102      5/31/2022      100
101      6/30/2022      25
101      1/31/2022      50
102      1/31/2022      100
101      2/28/2022      25
101      3/31/2022      50
102      3/31/2022      100
103      4/30/2022      25
103      5/31/2022      50
102      5/31/2022      100
101      6/30/2022      25
;;;;
    run;

proc summary data=amount nway;
    class date id;
    output out=out1(drop=_type_ rename=(_freq_=obs));
    run;
proc summary data=out1 nway;
    class date;
    output out=out2(drop=_type_) sum(obs)=;
    run;
proc print;
    run;
```

Comment: Could `hpsummary` be an option here as well?

Comment: @StuSztukowski I tried it by simply changing summary to HPsummary and got the same result.  I think I need to learn the PERFORMANCE statement and generate a large test data to know for sure.  I guess the answer is probably. :-)

Comment: Consider date is stored as integers in SAS, I sugguest you add `notrap` option to accelerate `proc summary`.